# Why java.util.Hashtable marked as 'obsolete collection' in Netbeans 8?

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, hashtable

When I import java.util.Hashtable in my code in Netbeans 8 the IDE suggest that it is obsolete collection. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)!**

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

Comment: Your post does not answer the question! I still don't know why Hashtable is worse than ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: @Tinki: `ConcurrentHashMap` is faster, and has a much safer API.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/